# Jquery Change input attribute password to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a jQuery beginner and I need your help to solve my one week lasting problem.
I have a table of (login, password, button) as in the picture below.
I want to show the hidden password for only 5 seconds and then hide it again, and this for only the row that the button is clicked.
Problem : 
- when one button is clicked, everything is ok.
- when another button is clicked, the first password also is shown.Can somebody help me fix that ?

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 //--------------------------------------
 $("table input[type='button']").on("click",function() {
 var element_td = $(this).parent('td');
 var element_tr = element_td.parent('tr'); 
 var element_input = element_tr.find("input[type='password']");
 $("#form-inner").show();
 //--------------------------------------
 function truePswd(password) {
  var password = $('#password').val();
  if (password == '') {
  alert ("Empty password");
  return false;
  }
  else
  {
  return true;
  }
 }
 $("#ok").on("click",function() {

 //----------------------------------------
 var result =truePswd (password);
    if (result == true) {
  var password = $('#password').val();
  $.ajax ({
  type : 'POST',
  cache : 'false',
  url : 'process.php',
  data : 'password ='+password,
  success : function(data) {
  $("#form-inner").hide();

  if(data = 'ok') {

  element_input.addClass('evidence');
  element_input.attr('type', 'text'); 
  
 //-----------------------------------------
  setTimeout(function() {
  element_input.removeClass('evidence');
  element_input.attr('type', 'password'); 
   
  }, 
  10000
  );
 //-----------------------------------------
  }
  },
  error : function() {
  alert("Error Ajax request");
  }
  });
  }
 });
 });

 //------------------------------------------
 });
```

```html
  <table>
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <td>login</td>
    <td>password</td>
    <td>action</td>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   <tr id="1">
    <td>admin</td>
    <td>
     <input type="password" value="n1mD@_!21&$"/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="button" value="show password"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="2">
    <td>lynxus</td>
    <td>
     <input type="password" value="l1ncSU$"/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="button" value="show password"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="3">
    <td>zeus76</td>
    <td>
     <input type="password" value="d1L&m@4_714"/>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="button" value="show password"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRHQu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Here try this.. I hope this is what you are looking for...

here's a fiddle for you to check:https://jsfiddle.net/sgvwume3/1/

here's the **Jquery Code**:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  $parent = $this.parent().parent();
  $td = $parent.find('td:eq(1)');
  sample($this, $td);

})

function sample($this, $input){
    var input = $input;
    $this.promise(
    input.find('.inputClass').attr('type', 'text')
  ).done(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    input.find('.inputClass').attr('type', 'password');
    }, 3000);
  });
}
```

Comment: I have set 3seconds there which is `3000`.. you can change it to five seconds by changing the 3000 to 5000.